# Did NASA ever use astronomical symbols for planets?

Tags: terminology

In 19th century texts on astronomy, the planets are often represented by [symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols): ☿ for Mercury, ♀ for Venus, etc..

Did NASA ever use these symbols, or were they already obsolete by then?  If they did use them, I'd expect it to be very early on.

Comment: Use them for what purpose?

Comment: @coleopterist, for any purpose, actually.  I've seen them in things from the 1800s and earlier.  The only place I can recall seeing them in use from the 1900s was the text adventure game *Trinity*.

Comment: FWIW, symbols were in use in the 20th century too. One of the reasons why the name _Pluto_ was accepted in 1930 was because its first two letters _PL_ were the initials of Percival Lowell, the founder of the Lowell Observatory (which discovered the "planet"). Pluto's astronomical symbol is ♇.

Comment: I know I've seen them in a trajectory design context before, and I know the symbol for Earth is often used (for example, as a subscript when describing the radius of the Earth). If I can find a published example I'll make an actual answer.

Comment: "[The International Astronomical Union discourages the use of these symbols in journal articles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols#Symbols_for_the_planets)" ([The IAU Style Manual, 1989 - The Preparation of Astronomical Papers and Reports](http://www.iau.org/static/publications/stylemanual1989.pdf))

Comment: Does anyone know what [this script](https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/plot/sunsymbol.pro) was used for? It seems to have still been in use at least as recently as February 2013.

Comment: NASA's early days coincide with the advent of computers. Those early computers often didn't support symbols other than ASCII (or EBCDIC etc.) which would have provided pressure not to use them.

Comment: @s-m-e: This is interesting. But is there any newer style manual, that is equally discouraging the use, or has there been a retraction of this policy with the advent of Tex?

Comment: @Hobbes I understand that. I'm asking more why they needed to generate this symbol often enough to need a script.

Comment: 30 years ago I helped maintain a piece of NASA software that used them - well some of them, as the Earth, Sun and inner planets were not something we needed to display. It was never used (AFAIK) for external purposes (and really had no use outside a fairly small NASA/contractor group). Does this count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the strictest sense of use "for any purpose" as you say in the comments, yes. Taken from [NASA page on Solar System Symbols](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/multimedia/display.cfm?IM_ID=167):

> [image]
>
> The symbols for the planets, dwarf planet Pluto, Moon and Sun (along
>   with the symbols for the zodiac constellations) were developed for use
>   in both astronomy and astrology.
>
> The astronomical symbol for the Sun is a shield with a circle inside.
>   Some believe this inner circle, or "boss" represents a central sun
>   spot.
>
> The symbol for Mercury represents the head and winged cap of Mercury,
>   god of commerce and communication, surmounting his caduceus (staff).
>
> The symbol for Venus is designated as the female symbol, thought to be
>   the stylized representation of the hand mirror of this goddess of
>   love.
>
> The symbol for Earth shows a globe bisected by meridian lines into
>   four quarters.
>
> The symbol for the Moon is a crescent.
>
> The symbol for Mars represents the shield and spear of the god of war,
>   Mars; it is also the male or masculine symbol.
>
> The symbol for Jupiter is said to represent a hieroglyph of the eagle,
>   Jove's bird, or to be the initial letter of Zeus with a line drawn
>   through it to indicate its abbreviation.
>
> The symbol for Saturn is thought to be an ancient scythe or sickle, as
>   Saturn was the god of seed-sowing and also of time.
>
> The symbol for Uranus is represented by combined devices indicating
>   the Sun plus the spear of Mars, as Uranus was the personification of
>   heaven in Greek mythology, dominated by the light of the Sun and the
>   power of Mars.
>
> The symbol for Neptune is the trident (long three-pronged fork or
>   weapon) of Neptune, god of the sea.
>
> The symbol for dwarf planet Pluto is a monogram made up of P and L in
>   Pluto (and also the initials of Percival Lowell, who predicted its
>   discovery).
>
> Credit: Lunar and Planetary Institute

All the planets of our Solar system have similar pages of their own, also using [astronomical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols), for example [Neptune's Symbol page](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/multimedia/display.cfm?Category=Planets&IM_ID=265). The credited [Lunar and Planetary Institute](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/) is a NASA funded institute in Houston, Texas, devoted to studying the solar system and sharing the excitement of space exploration with the public.

Being somewhat time-constraint, I wasn't able to find any mission imagery (observation data, telemetry data readings, mission control software, or any other such media with possible notations) that would use these astronomical symbols for planets. But as the time goes by, I'm pretty sure someone will find something, and I don't see why NASA using astronomical symbols also for other uses besides acknowledging they exist and describing them would even be considered anything unusual. Press kits might be watered down for easier consumption of the general populace, but for their internal use and where as concise as possible notations would be required not to obstruct other meaningful data, I imagine they'd use them frequently.

Comment: It's kind of sad that you, literally, for the first time in my life, have me understanding the origin of the phrase "Women are from Venus, men are from Mars" and the joking addition "... but my spouse is from Mercury."

Answer (score 12):

They have absolutely used these, in various mission badges:

This was the logo for the Mercury project:

[image]

Here's a patch from the Viking program:

[image]
<sub>(source: [colostate.edu](http://rammb.cira.colostate.edu/dev/hillger/Viking_mission-patch.jpg))</sub>

And one from Mariner 2, to Venus:

[image]

None of these are for any sort of technical reason; I'm sure the symbols aren't used for anything important, but as a little bit of astronomical history, they're not completely forgotten, either.

Comment: And the circles with a cross or a dot are commonly used in diagrams of papers and presentations to represent the Sun or Earth, usually their mass.

Answer (score 5):

Mariner Jupiter Saturn, later named Project Voyager, initially had the Jupiter and Saturn symbols on the project logo.[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the astronomical literature and therefore by NASA, at least the Earth and Sun symbol are used by standard to denote parameters like radius, mass, luminosity of the Earth and the Sun. It is customary to denote $\rm R_{\oplus}$, and $\rm R_{\odot}$, whereas for Jupiter (probably as it is not implemented in standard latex) one nowadays usually uses $\rm R_{J}$ or $\rm R_{Jup}$.